# Condition For Select Output based on distance between two different GIS Nodes

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to find a condition to put in select output that is based on distance between two GIS points. My network includes a tram with people and I want my person to get off at tram stop nearest to its house. The tram moves in a counter loop and I want to place condition so that the person exits drops off at the right tram stop. Could you please help me with it?

I have already tried distanceByRoute but I don't know how to form a condition for it via statechart or in selectOutput.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4PYu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumptions

- You have a population of *Station*-Agents named *stations*
- You have a population of *Passenger*-Agents named *passengers*
- You have a population of *Tram*-Agents named *trams*
- You have a population of *Home*-Agents named *homes*

---

#### Step by step

1. Add to*Tram*-Agent a variable *nextStation* of type *Station* in which the moveTo-Block always saves the current arrival station
2. Add to *Passenger*-Agent a parameter of type *Home* named *home* where at model startup a *Home*-Agent is filled in
3. Create a function named *getNearestStation*, with a input parameter of type *Passenger* and output of type *Station*:

[image: Function Definition]

```java
    //initialize with first station
    Station nearestStation = stations.get(0);
    double distanceToNearestStation = passenger.home.distanceByRoute(nearestStation);
    double currentDistance;
    
    for(Station station:stations){
        currentDistance = passenger.home.distanceByRoute(station);
        //save it if you find a closer station
        if( currentDistance < distanceToNearestStation){
            nearestStation = station;
            distanceToNearestStation = passenger.home.distanceByRoute(station);
        }
    }
    
    return nearestStation;
```

Instead of having a *Station* Agent, you could also use *GISPoint* for both your Variable nextStation inside tram and in the getNearestStation code.

4. Add a dropoff-Block to your flowchart and set the dropoff condition to the following:
   `getNearestStation(agent).equals(container.nextStation)`

[image: Dropoff-Block]

---

#### Additional note

In order to make the distance calculation less often, execute the *getNearestStation* only once at initialization of each passenger and save it in a variable, instead of calculating it each time it passes the dropoff block.

Comment: The condition in drop-off isn't working for me. Its either that I don't know how to state inputs and outputs for the function (I am writing them in the argument section for function) or something else I can't figure. Also, I want to use combine and split instead of drop-off because passenger is more like an object that is combining with the tram for me. Could you help me with it?

Comment: 1) "passenger not resolved": To the input parameter of the function getNearestStation you have to give the name "passenger"

2) "The method getNearestStation....": I see you defined Passenger and Station as input parameters. It should only be passenger to work with my code. Also you execute the function with a Tram as parameter, you need to give it a reference to passenger.

3)-5) It seems you have defined the parameters/variables nextStation and counter as static ? Not really sure...

Comment: Sorry if my questions are generic. I have already gone through Anylogic tutorials and everything , but I am beginner in Java and figuring out how functions operate. I am doing agent based modelling with tram as an agent, within tram I have GisPoints as my stations and a counter parameter that allows my tram to move from one stop to the other. I have passenger as an agent and for now iwant to move only one person on  the tram. I combine the tram and passenger at Hbf and I want to split them near the home (currently a GIS location) and I don't know how to integrate your function with my model.

Comment: I added another screenshot on how to define the function in AnyLogic with input and output parameters. I modeled Stations and Homes as Agents, but you can use the same with GISPoints, just exchange the type in all relevant places (nextStation Variable in Tram, home Variable in Passenger and in the getNearestStation function body + return type).

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you again and again :-( But I still can't Figure it out on how to convert to GisPoints (INode) in function body, specially when distance is concerned. I am adding my screenshot in the answer box.

Comment: @RaheenKhalid, I think my answer is not helping you or anybody else. Can I ask you to uncheck "accepted answer" so that I can delete it and maybe somebody else can provide a better answer?

Comment: No need to do that. I edited some things in my model and the code and made it work as per your method. Thank you so much for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCUxg.png)

tramCollection here is my collection of tram stops (in GIS/INode) located on my map in Main.